Static electricity found on the metal part of the computer case usually means that there is a short circuit in one of the computer hardware?
I am a competent computer user and I do not understand much about electrical currents on electronic items.
I'm not talking about the static electricity that comes from the user which is the electricity that passes from our hands to the computer case. I'm talking about the static electricity charge that accumulates on the metal parts of the computer case, which we can test with some tools. It's usually means that there is a short circuit problem in one of the internal components of the computer?

No. If you get an electric shock (or you feel the electricity when you rub the case but you don't get a shock) when touching the computer case, then that simply means that the computer is not grounded properly.
The electronic components will dump its redundant electricity to ground, and ground is normally transferred to the ground pin on your PSU to the wall.
It is therefor normally required to put the computer in an earthed electrical socket, but there are locations in the world, where you can actually use an earthed plug in a non-earthed socket without a problem, and it also happens that people improperly install an earthed socket without connecting earth.
The computer will work fine, except that there is a static build-up that may lead to a shock if the ground to earth path is created through your body.

I understand. No matter what was plugged into the motherboard, static electricity was constantly coming from the case, I completely removed the parts and put them back, I don't know what changed but I tried for 1 hour, no static electricity came from the case metal, I tested it with a test pen. I think there are two possibilities, either there is an electrical leak from the chassis or the PSU is faulty and causes a short circuit if used for a long time and compulsively during the day.

Let me try a little more and understand what the problem is exactly, there is no static electricity for now, I will strain the computer a little and see what happens, if there is a sudden electrical leak, it means there may be a fault in the PSU.

Electrical leaks are not a thing. If a computer case is properly grounded then it cannot generate a electrical charge.

This is a cumulative over time thing. It will build up as you use the computer, if the computer is not properly grounded. The moment you touch the chassis and form a ground, it will drain all electrical energy right away. If it was sufficient, you will feel it, if it was not, you will not even feel it. If a part of the case now hits something else that is grounded, it will leak that way.

Computer is properly grounded, the building is grounded, the socket is grounded, the PSU cable is grounded. It may seem strange but we found out that the problem is plastic slippers. If the person touching the computer case is wearing slippers and walks around with those slippers for a while, they get a slight static electric shock, if they are not wearing them, nothing happens.

In other words, the exact opposite of the question title, we determined that the electric shock is not from the computer case to the person, but from the person to the case, because we determined that the same friend was electrocuted on the metal surfaces when he touched other metal surfaces with those slippers.

I think the PSU or mobo is damaged because from time to time the devices in the safe would momentarily deactivate and then come back on but it's fine for now, maybe it's because of something else, I don't know. In fact, it is not a low and bad computer, it's just fine.

@Spacewizard - While not scientific, YouTubers have generated a static charge and purposely touched motherboards, without causing a problem with the hardware. What you described sounds more of unstable power more than anything.
